# user defined scrollbar y-axis plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any one know/have URL links for user defined scrollbar plug-in's in jQuery?
I want to use overflow-y:scroll similar functionality. Images and functionality
I want to replace in that vertical scroll bar as per functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is jScrollPane: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Here is a demo where you can see the horizontal bar in action: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

Comment: @poineer , i used jscrollpanel from kelvinluck , and its really nice